# How to define custom nodemon configuration in nodemonConfig in package.json?

Tags: node.js, express, nodes, nodemon, grunt-nodemon

I tried implementing custom nodemon configuration in package.json as shown below:

```
"nodemonConfig": {
    "watch": ["server", "bin/www"],
    "ext": "ts",
    "ignore": ["*.test.ts"],
    "delay": "3000",
    "execMap": {
      "ts": "ts-node"
    }
  }
```

Yet, it didn't work. Nodemon doesn't restart when ./bin/www is edited, nor does ignoring the files that restart the server works.

Can anyone suggest me the correct nodemonConfig?

Answer (score 3):

I think these settings only work when npm is starting nodemon, something like

```
// package.json
"scripts": {
  "start:dev": "DEBUG=app:* nodemon app.js"
}
```

then use

> $> npm run start:dev

Comment: when i added 'DEBUG=app:*' - i get error: No matches found: "app:*"

Answer (score 1):

package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node index.js",
    "dev": "nodemon index.js"
  },
```

Terminal

```
npm run dev
```

Answer (score 0):

You were close. First piece of advice is when you're having issues, add the `verbose` flag.

Second, although you correctly configured `nodemon` options and mappings, you still need to tell it what to execute (`bin/www`).

Your package.json should look like this:

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon bin/www"
  },
  "nodemonConfig": {
    "verbose": true,
    "watch": ["server", "bin/www"],
    "ext": "ts",
    "ignore": ["*.test.ts"],
    "delay": "3000",
    "execMap": {
      "ts": "ts-node"
    }
  }
}
```

Note: `execMap` already defaults to `ts-node`, see [defaults.js](https://github.com/remy/nodemon/blob/master/lib/config/defaults.js).